# How do you check if any objects in an array has a property with value in Azure Logic App?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-resource-manager

I am building a Azure Logic App which recieves a webhook. I need to parse the body and validate if a array contains any object with a property that matches either of two values, but have no idea how to do it.

Any ideas?

The JSON i am recieving in the webhook is like below, shortened for brevity. I am looking at the components-array:

```
{
    "id": "12601",
    "components": [
        {
            "id": "10021",
            "name": "Value1"
        },
        {
            "id": "10022",
            "name": "Value2"
        },
        {
            "id": "10023",
            "name": "Value3"
        }
    ]
}
```

From this array I need to output a parameter true/false if any properties with name == "Value1" or "Value" appears.

Is there any syntax similar to LINQ in C#, or do you use a foreach? I have not been able to find any simple way like:

If(Arr.Any(x => x.name == "Value1"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can use [Parse Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action) to parse the Json string you received, and then use [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-conditional-statement#add-condition) to determine whether the name contains value1.

Please refer to my logic app:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is great, I set it up like you, parsing the json body and then controlling on the output. Great stuff, thank you!